# É possível determinar se um array de bytes representa um arquivo pdf que não pode ser editado?

Tags: c#, pdf

### Contexto

Eu tenho dois passos no meu serviço, o upload e o download do arquivo.
No upload no serviço recebo os dados **através de um array de bytes ASCII**.

Esses dados são armazenados em um banco de dados. No download, os dados referentes ao arquivo são buscados no banco e são escritos em binário para um arquivo temporário.

A partir daí, coloco uma marca d'água, e retorno o download do arquivo final para o usuário. **Trata-se de um arquivo PDF**.

### O Problema

O problema é que quando o usuário faz upload de um arquivo (PDF) que não pode ser editado. Não se trata de um atributo somente leitura, pois os dados estão sendo buscados no banco, e não no computador do usuário.

O que caracteriza a *"editabilidade"* do arquivo é uma permissão atribuída dentro do formato PDF quando o arquivo é **protegido**.

### Objetivo

Aquilo que busco entender é se existe uma maneira de identificar se o arquivo:

1. É um PDF protegido
2. Se a permissão de edição foi atribuída pelo criador do arquivo

Para que eu possa tratar o fluxo da aplicação e impedir que um arquivo não-editável seja armazenado no banco de dados (e, eventualmente, um erro seja lançado por não poder adicionar a marca d'água.).

```
Exemplo do byte[]:

    [0] 37  

    [1] 80  

    [2] 68  

    [...] ... 

    [84006] 10
```

Lembrando que, atualmente, minha solução é gravar o arquivo em um local temporário dentro do servidor para fazer essa verificação. Desejo evitar essa etapa e realizar qualquer verificação diretamente no array de dados que recebo do banco.

Para reconstruir o arquivo a partir dos dados armazenados no banco, utilizo do seguinte recurso:

```
BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.OpenWrite(fileName));
Writer.Write("variavel_byte[]");
```

Comment: Amigo, dei uma olhada na especificação do PDF (link abaixo) e encontrei um trecho que indica se um documento é CRIPTOGRAFADO, entretanto por falta de tempo (confesso) não poderia estudar a fundo o assunto pra te ajudar. Como sua necessidade é premente talvez te dando o caminho você consiga terminar o estudo.

Ao final do texto do PDF existe sessão chamada Trailer. Se houver uma uma chave /Encrypt isso indica que o documento possui alguma proteção. Os números que seguem /Encrypt indicam qual o objeto responsável pela criptografia e quais níveis de acesso são garantidos (continua).

Comment: Assim sendo um Trailer com conteúdo "/Encrypt 30 0 R" indica que você deve observar o conteúdo do objeto "30 0" para verificar suas permissões. Procure o trecho "30 0 obj" para encontrar os níveis de acesso do documento, dentro desse objeto existirão algumas outras especificações. Atente-se ao /Filter (que indica qual filtro será usado) e ao /R (que indica a revisão), eles têm influência nos valores a serem procurados e onde procurá-los. Assumindo um valor /Standard o documento traz informações de como gerenciar essas permissões (págs. 74 a 77).

Comment: (continuando). Procure os valores /P para identificar as permissões. Seu estudo continua à partir daqui... rsrsrs... Segue o link para a referência da especificação  PDF 1.4 (para outras versões desconheço se há modificações nessas permissões).

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Há uma solução sem usar o Array de Bytes utilizando o iTextSharp, com array de bytes não encontrei nada, inclusive em outras pesquisas todas apontam para os componentes.

> PM> Install-Package iTextSharp

---

```
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

    private void CheckPdfProtection()
    {
        var filePath = @"c:\temp\EmploymentHistory.pdf";
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(filePath))
        {
            if (!reader.IsEncrypted()) return;

            if (!PdfEncryptor.IsPrintingAllowed(Convert.ToInt32(reader.Permissions)))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Arquivo protegido para impressão");
            if (!PdfEncryptor.IsModifyContentsAllowed(Convert.ToInt32(reader.Permissions)))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Arquivo protegido para escrita");
        }
    }
```